On rotund points in the second dual of a Banach space
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual (the space of continuous linear functionals $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$). Let $B_X$ and $S_X$ be the unit ball and unit sphere of $X$, respectively. A point $x \in S_X$ is said to be a rotund point of $B_{X^{**}}$ if any $y^{**} \in S_{X^{**}}$ satisfies $\frac{x + y^{**}}{2} \in S_{X^{**}}$, then it is the case that $x = y^{**}$. Let $x \in S_X$. Consider the following statement.
(a) For every $x^* \in D(x)$ and for any sequence $\{x_n\} \subset S_X$, the condition $x^*(x_n) \to 1$ implies $x_n \to x$ weakly.
Prove that (a) implies that $x$ is a rotund point of $B_{X^{**}}$.
My approach: To show $x$ is a rotund point of $B_{X^{**}}$, let $y^{**} \in S_{X^{**}}$ with $\frac{x + y^{**}}{2} \in S_{X^{**}}$. Then there exists $\{x_n^*\} \subset S_{X^*}$ such that $x_n^*(x) \to 1$ and $y^{**}(x_n^*) \to 1$. If $y^*$ is a w$^*$-cluster point of $\{x_n^*\},$ then we get $y^*(x)=1,$ i.e., $y^*\in D(x).$
After this, how do I proceed? This has been discussed here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268641467_Rotund_points_nested_sequence_of_balls_and_smoothness_in_Banach_spaces
Edit: For $x\in S_X,$ the set $D(x)=\{x^*\in S_{X^*}: x^*(x)=1\}.$

What exactly is $D(x)$?

Please see the Edit @Evangelopoulos Foivos
